# prove convergence of the sequence cos(1/n) using formal definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta, formal-proofs

prove that sequence $cos~(1/n)$ is converging to 1. using the definition.
ie, I want to find the $N$ corresponding to the $\epsilon$ in definition.
I am stuck with, whether i can use $cos^{-1}$ in both sides of inequality without altering sign of inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\cos (\frac 1 n) \geq 1-\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ so $|1-\cos (\frac 1 n)| <\epsilon$ if $n>\frac 1 {\sqrt{\epsilon}}$

Comment: proof for first inequality?

Comment: $\cos x=1-\frac {x^{2}} 2+(\frac {x^{4}} {4!}-\frac {x^{6}} {6!})+(\frac {x^{8}} {8!}-\frac {x^{10}} {(10)!})+...$. For $0<x<1$ it is easy to check that  $(\frac {x^{4}} {4!}-\frac {x^{6}} {6!}),(\frac {x^{8}} {8!}-\frac {x^{10}} {(10)!}),...$ are all positive.

Comment: thanks a lot sir

Comment: If I want to find smallest N such that, conditions are met. How can I do

Comment: @sabeelmsk on $[0,\pi /2]$ cosine is strictly decreasing. So $1-\cos (\frac 1 n) <\epsilon$ iff $\frac 1 n < \cos^{-1}(1-\epsilon)$ iff $n >\frac 1 {\cos^{-1} (1-\epsilon)}$.